# Special crontab expression

Tags: cron

just to verify my understanding of cron-syntax, the following expression will fire on a saturday at 02:42 in the middle of the month, right?

42 02 12-19 * 6 myScript > /dev/null 2>&1

cheers
Nicolaie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script `myScript` (not good without a path here!) will be executed at 2:42 indeed, on every day between and including the 12th to the 19th of each month that is a saturday.

Comment: Thanks arkascha,
thats what i wanted.
Never mind the path. It was just an example!
;-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually

`42 02 12-19 * 6 myScript > /dev/null 2>&1`

means run on 12 thru 19 and every Saturday.

You need a more complex line to do what you state:

`0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"`

is an example from the manfile on my system.  It uses a trivial execution after making sure it is Saturday.

See http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/ as well as `> man 5 crontab` (at the commandline) for more.